# Can Octave/Matlab work in integer fractions

Tags: matlab, octave

I have written 2 small programs to implement the Conjugate Gradient Method and the Gradient descent method but I am getting false results. I am interested in only doing a small number of steps and getting the exact answers from the iteration but Octave and Matlab give me wrong results with **format rat**.

Is there a way to force Matlab or Octave to work in integer fractions?

```
       clc,clear
    format rat
    A=[1 1 2;1 10 8;2 8 12] 
    b=[3;1;3];
    X=[-1;0;0]
    r=b-A*X;
    p=r;
    k=0
    while k<2
        w=A*p;
        alpha=r'*p./(w'*p);
        X=X+alpha*p
        ralt=r;
        r=ralt-alpha*w;
        beta=r'*w./w'*p;
        p=r-beta*p;
        k=k+1
    end
    disp(X)
```

Output -317/450, 379/2565, 447/1210
Should be 10244/7981, -12141/15962, 21717/31924

Comment: We have no idea what your inputs, current outputs and expected outputs are. Help us with this and we might be able to help you. Otherwise it's really unclear what you're trying to achieve. In summary, what are your "*wrong results*" and why are they wrong?

Comment: The question isn't only specific to this problem. I want him know how to make matlab work with exclusively integer fractions

Comment: Your outputs are already in rational format. What is the question? Force computations to be done on a pair of `int`s instead of single `double`? Probably not. At least not without a significant effort in rewriting and recompiling the octave itself.

Comment: Yes thats what I mean. Do the arithmetic on rations of integers and not real numbers.